# parsing JSON object in javascript and finding the depth

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, web

I am trying to find the depth of a node and I am not able to understand the below code. "node" is a node object passed as input.

```
 for (key in node) 
    {
        if (node.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
        {
            child = node[key];
            if (typeof child === 'object' && child !== null && key != 'parent') 
            {
```

This is what I have understood so far:

- Each node that is passed - we go through its properties
- For each property , the value of the property becomes a child
- if the type of child is an object and if the child is not equal to null and the property is not equal to the parent "node" that was passed. ( this part I dont understand)

Is my interpretation correct? Would appreciate any help. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`'parent'` appears to be a normal string, it's not a reserved word in javascript or builtin property of the JSON standard, and from what I can tell you're not being passed the parent node. If it's a reference to the parent node (in `node['parent']` ) I'm not sure what function it would serve (if this parser is walking a tree.

Do you have more code you can share? an example of the JSON being parsed would be useful. I would post this in a comment, but I don't have enough reputation, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Take this json as an example:

```
node = {'one': {'two': 3}, 'two':null, 'parent':4};
```

And now your code:

```
for (key in node) 
{
    if (node.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
    {
        child = node[key];
        if (typeof child === 'object' && child !== null && key != 'parent') 
        {
```

In the if you will have only `child = {'two': 3}`. The rest of the items in `node` object do not respect `if` statement.

Basically you iterate thru `node` items, to find childs that are objects, does not contain a `null` value and their corresponding key is different than `parent`

Comment: what does parent refer to here ? Could you explain? You have included one of the properties as 'parent'

Comment: `parent` is just a key in your example. Is not something from javascript, its a string just like the keys `one` & `two`. And the code checks for every object that doesnt have the key equals to `parent`. Make sense?

Comment: okay. So 'parent' is a property of the object or the key of the node. But what is the purpose of ignoring the key with value 'parent'?

Comment: Ha ha. Good question. I can't know that. You need to check more in the place where you got the code from. For sure is not related to anything from javascript reserved words or object properties so you need to stop worrying about it as it not something you missed from JS book, it is only something related to the JSON passed to that function, its something custom, project specific probably.